# c# Json Serialization Required Fields

Tags: c#, api, serialization

I am using the inbuilt `DataContractJsonSerializer` to prepare data for transmission.

I am Serializing from a business object using the following code:

```
private string SerialiseRequest(RegistrationRequest request)
        {
            string strRequest = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(request.GetType());

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    serializer.WriteObject(ms, request);
                    strRequest = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            return strRequest;
        }
```

When the data is serialized, it seems to be ignoring the settings, the most important setting is IsRequired, as I do not want to transmit a field if it doesnt contain data. Here is how I have the Business Object Defined:

```
 [DataContract]
    public sealed class RegistrationRequest
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 0, IsRequired = true)]
        public Registration_Header registration_header { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
        public Customer_Details primary_user { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = true)]
        public StaffDetails partner_attributes { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 3, IsRequired = true)]
        public CustomerAddress primary_residential_address { get; set; }      

        public class Registration_Header
        {
            [DataMember(Order = 0, IsRequired = true)]
            public string services_required { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
            public string account_type { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = true)]
            public string affiliate_number { get; set; }
        }

        public class Customer_Details
        {
            [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
            public string title { get; set; }

            [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
            public string first_name { get; set; }

            [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
            public string middle_name { get; set; }

            [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
            public string last_name { get; set; }

            [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
            public string email { get; set; }

            [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
            public string nationality { get; set; }

            [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
            public string dob { get; set; }

            [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
            public string occupation { get; set; }

            [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
            public string residence_country { get; set; }

            [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
            public string mobile_number { get; set; }

            [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
            public string landline_number { get; set; }

            [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
            public string source { get; set; }
        }

        public class StaffDetails
        {
            [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
            public string reps_name { get; set; }

            [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
            public string reps_location { get; set; }

            [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
            public string customer_id { get; set; }
        }

        public class CustomerAddress
        {
            [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
            public string postcode { get; set; }

            [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
            public string street_or_address { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Name = "city", IsRequired = true)]
            public string city { get; set; }

            [DataMember(Name = "country", IsRequired = true)]
            public string country { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is a sample of the Serialized data that I am getting back from 'SerialiseRequest' Method:

> {"registration_header":{"account_type":"Single","affiliate_number":"A061535","services_required":"Transfers"},
>   "primary_user":{"dob":"23-10-1989","email":"k@gale","first_name":"Kathy","landline_number":"","last_name":"Gale","middle_name":"","mobile_number":"+44-79879879879","nationality":"UK","occupation":"Farmer","residence_country":"UK","source":"Other","title":"Miss"},
>   "partner_attributes":{"customer_id":"273098","reps_location":"Stockton-North
>   East UK","reps_name":"Richard Gale-551"},
>   "primary_residential_address":{"city":"Larkhall","country":"UK","postcode":"ML9
>   2LS","street_or_address":"1 The Street"}}

Comment: which field are required and are null at the presented json?

Comment: `try…catch…return string.Empty`. OMG!

Comment: @JhonatasKleinkauff The 2 fields which are not required are middle_name and landline_number.

As you can see in the ouput (above), they are included with an empty string, but I want them ommitting if there is no data.

Comment: @UweKeim, Is there a problem with returning an empty string?
The empty string is handled elsewhere in the coding by throwing an exception.

Comment: @Richard.Gale Of course this is a problem. You throw away all the valuable error information. To me the is is the anti-pattern of exception handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]` [attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
[DataContract]
public sealed class RegistrationRequest
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0, IsRequired = true)]
    public Registration_Header registration_header { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
    public Customer_Details primary_user { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = true)]
    public StaffDetails partner_attributes { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3, IsRequired = true)]
    public CustomerAddress primary_residential_address { get; set; }

    public class Registration_Header
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 0, IsRequired = true)]
        public string services_required { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
        public string account_type { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = true)]
        public string affiliate_number { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Customer_Details
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string first_name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string middle_name { get; set; }    

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string last_name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string nationality { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string dob { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string occupation { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string residence_country { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string mobile_number { get; set; }

        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string landline_number { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string source { get; set; }
    }

    public class StaffDetails
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string reps_name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string reps_location { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string customer_id { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerAddress
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string postcode { get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string street_or_address { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "city", IsRequired = true)]
        public string city { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "country", IsRequired = true)]
        public string country { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Also notice that you have to decorate the `Customer_Details` class with `[DataContract]` for it to take effect.

Comment: Thanks Erik, I will give that a whirl. It does pose the question, do I really need to include the (IsRequired = true) for all the other elements?

Comment: From what I can tell from the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.isrequired(v=vs.110).aspx) it will be checked when reading or deserializing and throw an error accordingly. Depends what kind of behaviour you want to impose on the client side of things. And another [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/best-practices-data-contract-versioning) concerning best practices for datacontracts-

Comment: @Richard.Gale Personally, I wouldn't use `IsRequired=true` except if I'd really want to enforce this property always being there. That means every deserialization from JSON to C# object.

Comment: I have updated to remove all of the [IsRequired=true] settings, and placed the (EmitDefaultValue=false) on middle_name and landline_number, but they are both still being output by the serializer. Any ideas?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Can you check if the object you're serializing actually has middle_name=null and not middle_name="".

Comment: yes that was the issue, the fields were String.Empty rather than null. thanks for all your input

Answer (score 0):

The Serializer is only going to serialize the data in the object.  It won't carry the decorations on the class.  The IsRequired attribute will trigger when the DataContract is sent back to the service.

Comment: So are you saying this is not the correct way to omit fields which have no data?

Comment: Ah! please pardon me.  I missed the part where he said he didn't want to transmit fields that have no data. I think Erik has the best answer.